# Upload timestamped file with SFTP using WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I am making a batch file to upload a file to one specific folder on SFTP server. When I run the file with task scheduler it shows me no error, but nothing is uploaded on the client's SFTP folder. Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off

REM Defines an exiting variable to be added onto each file giving it a time-stamp and exiting the current instance of WinSCP.
set d=%date:~-4,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~-7,2%
set d=%d: =_%

REM Creates the variable lines to shorten the SFTP file upload.
REM Example usage --> %transferStart%ourFile.txt %transferEnd%TheirFile.txt%e%
SET upload=winscp.exe /console /command "option confirm off" "open sftp://user:pass@example.com" "c:\apps\ftpfiles\name_%d%.txt" "put \\mainfolder\inbound\" "close"
```

Comment: are you missing closing quotes at the end ?

Comment: no, in original version I have the closing code, I added here as well. Thanks for letting me know of that.

Comment: I have it in the code, still no results.

Comment: I also added "-hostkey="ssh-rsa 22 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" at the end of my sftp open statement, but it didn't change any thing

Comment: `c:\apps:\ftpfiles\name_%d%.txt` has a `:` after `apps` which is invalid.

Comment: thanks I fixed that as well, still not working

Comment: You set an `upload` environment variable and never use it. So WinSCP is never executed. Did you even bother to test the batch file from a command-line/console? Remove the `SET upload=` part or use the `upload` like `%upload%`.

Comment: I did remove the set upload file , that didn't work

Comment: So what if you include your current version of the batch file in your question? Also replace the `winscp.exe` with `winscp.com`. And include the batch-file output.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of problems in your batch-file. I can identify at least:

- You set the environment variable `upload` (for a reason I do not understand), and you do not use it. Call WinSCP directly instead:

  ```
  winscp.exe /console /command ...
  ```
- While not strictly wrong, using the `winscp.exe` (GUI application) from a batch-file complicates debugging (it starts a separate window or the WinSCP process). Use the [`winscp.com` (console application)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) instead. With the `winscp.com`, the `/console` parameter is redundant:

  ```
  winscp.com /command ...
  ```
- You use the file name `"c:\apps\ftpfiles\name_%d%.txt"` as if it were a command. If you want to upload this specific file, use the path in the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put):

  ```
  "put c:\apps\ftpfiles\name_%d%.txt"
  ```
- You are missing the `-hostkey` switch in the [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) to [verify your server's hostkey](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).
- You are missing the [`exit` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_exit) (and the `close` before the `exit` is redundant).
- Obtaining timestamp from the `date` environment variable is unreliable (the value of `date` is locale-specific). Use the WinSCP [`%TIMESTAMP%` construct](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

  ```
  "put c:\apps\ftpfiles\name_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%.txt"
  ```

  (You need to use the WinSCP 5.7 or later for the `%TIMESTAMP%`.)
- With the latest version of WinSCP, the [`option confirm off` is unnecessary](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#using_scripting).

All that applied, your batch file will consist of a single command:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://user:pass@example.com -hostkey=""your-servers-hostkey""" ^
    "put c:\apps\ftpfiles\name_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. I used the timestamp you provided but it's the task scheduler is giving me incorrect function when I am adding this. %TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%

Comment: Sorry, but that's very vague. What does it mean "task scheduler is giving me incorrect function"?

Comment: this is the msg in last run result of the task: "Invalid Function". I just noticed we are using WinSCP 5.1.1 is this %TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd% working on this version as well?

Comment: No it is not. That's why I explicitly mentioned, you need to use WinSCP 5.7 or later. Though I do not think the "Invalid Function" message is related to that.